# use macro token in pragma result in incorrect substitution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, pragma

I'm trying to use macro with "pragma include_alias" in VS2010, but I got a odd compiling warning which means the substitution is incorrect.
Here is the code:

```
18 #define RAPID_INCLUDES_PATH(MY_TARGET_HEADERS)  "C:\\thirdpart\\rapidxml-1.13\\" ##  #MY_TARGET_HEADERS  
19 #define TEST(empty) "C:\\thirdpart\\rapidxml-1.13\\rapidxml_print.hpp"

//WORKS
21 #pragma include_alias( "rapidxml.hpp",  "C:\\thirdpart\\rapidxml-1.13\\rapidxml.hpp"  )
22 #pragma include_alias( "rapidxml_print.hpp" , TEST(empty) )

//FAILS
23 #pragma include_alias( "rapidxml_utils.hpp" , RAPID_INCLUDES_PATH(rapidxml_utils.hpp) )
24 #pragma include_alias( "rapidxml_iterators.hpp" , RAPID_INCLUDES_PATH(rapidxml_iterators.hpp)   )


26 #include "rapidxml.hpp"
27 #include "rapidxml_iterators.hpp"
28 #include "rapidxml_print.hpp"
29 #include "rapidxml_utils.hpp"
```

The error messages:

```
1>  Touching "Debug\xml2.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>d:\workspace\v10\xml2\xml2\stdafx.h(23): warning C4081: expected ')'; found 'string'
1>d:\workspace\v10\xml2\xml2\stdafx.h(24): warning C4081: expected ')'; found 'string'
1>d:\workspace\v10\xml2\xml2\stdafx.h(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rapidxml_iterators.hpp': No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
```

It seems there're some misuses of macro.
Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks a lots.

Comment: This really makes me cringe, absolute paths in source files is a big no no, but that's obviously just my opinion.

Comment: Indeed, directly adding PATH in additional include files may be more proper way, but I still hope to know the reason of incorrect substitution.

Comment: Tried right click -> properties on stdafx.cpp, then C/C++ -> Command Line and add /P (iirc) to Additional options? This will give you the pre processed source file, which should allow you to track down what the macro is incorrectly expanding to. Another tip is the fact that `"foo" "bar"` is a valid construct that actually is the two string concatenated, so ## might be superfluous in this case.

Comment: Thanks Ylisar! I found it will generate "C:\\thirdpart\\rapidxml-1.13\\""rapidxml_utils.hpp"  , there're two additional quotation...hmmm